# Many to one unidirectional rows with null value are not showing up

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have two tables

`TableA`, `TableB`  with many to one relationship defined in hbm.xml

Example:

TableA

Because uni-directional relationship (only `TableA` to `TableB`) there are no entries in `TableB` `hbm.xml` related to `TableA`

Now the issue is, `TableA` may have **null** values for `columnIDFromTableA` and when I query `TableA`, these rows also should showup apart from matching rows from TableB, but it is not working.

The query I have is:

```
select column1, column2, tableA.tableB.someColumn from TableA tableA left outer join tableA.tableB as tabB where column1  Like '%someval%'
```

Above query returning ZERO rows.

As soon as I remove column related to tableB (in this case tableA.tableB.someColumn) from query, I am getting expected results

```
select column1, column2 from TableA tableA left outer join tableA.tableB as tabB where column1  Like '%someval%'
```

above query returning expected results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
tableA.tableB.someColumn
```

, you create an implicit inner join between the tables.

You already have a left outer join between the tables:

```
from TableA tableA left outer join tableA.tableB as tabB
```

So you just need to use the alias you assigned to this left joined entity:

```
select column1, column2, tabB.someColumn 
from TableA tableA 
left outer join tableA.tableB as tabB 
where column1  Like '%someval%'
```

Side note: your query would be much more readable if you used aliases systematically:

```
select tableA.column1, tableA.column2, tableB.someColumn 
from TableA tableA 
left outer join tableA.tableB as tableB 
where tableA.column1 like '%someval%'
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer (to be frank you were the one in my mind while typing question), sorry about alias using. Let me try your suggestion.

Comment: +1. It seems that is the issue. May be you need to make this as Wiki answer. People may do this mistake very frequently by using object association instead of joined entity alias. I am testing further, but I got some clues on how to proceed. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: In my experience, that won't help. I keep answering countless questions about Hibernate and JPA (very often the same), which are answered in the official documentation or the javadoc. It's sad, but many programmers can't read documentation, or are too lazy to do it.